# 22.04 upgrade multiple monitor issue, no longer able to detect hdmi

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell Latitude E6420 laptop that has a vga and hdmi port, and I was able to run 2 additional monitors in a addition to the laptop built in display using 20.04.

After upgrading to 22.04, only the VGA monitor shows up in the display configuration.

The Settings-> About-> Graphics shows "NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [NVS 4200M] / Intel® HD Graphics 3000"

The dell website shows system configuration for the laptop shows nVidia NVS 4200M 512MB DDR3 Di screte Graphics, Dell Latitude E6420.

It seems that the hdmi port is not found.

xrandr only shows the vga and the laptop built in display.

richie@BOSS:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 2820, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+1920 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
1600x900      60.06*+  40.32
1400x900      59.88
1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85
1280x800      59.81    59.91
1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74
1024x768      60.00
1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82
960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82
800x600       60.32    56.25
864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57
800x450       60.00
640x480       59.94
720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99
640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
VGA1 connected primary 1200x1920+196+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
1920x1200     59.95*+
1600x1200     60.00
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1152x864      75.00
1024x768      75.03    60.00
800x600       75.00    60.32
640x480       75.00    59.94
720x400       70.08
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Thanks for any assistance.
Richard

Comment: This issue seems to be only impacting my user - richie

Comment: This issue seems to be only impacting my user - richie...  I have been reading many posts about nvdia issues and did a grub boot to root. I then removed nvidia and was at the login loop issue. I did a grub boot and selected root shell and tried nearly every suggested step in this forum.   Currently at the point where I created a 'test' user from the tty3 and tried gui login with that user - no loop and the hdmi is now available..